# Angular routing delay

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am fairly new to Angular so still getting used to the routing functionality.

I have a click through wizard and on the final step, there is a 'Complete' button which should post to the DB and route the user to a certain page. However, I have a timing issue in that the user is routed to the page before the DB insert is completed, meaning the page doesn't show their newly created review.

```
    next() {
        this.reviewOutput.emit(this.formGroup.value);
        delay(1000);
        this.router.navigate(['/reviews']);
    }
```

The /reviews component selects all the user's reviews from the DB upon loading, but this is being done before the review has been added to the DB.

Adding the delay of 1 second solves the issue but isn't very 'clean' nor is it good practice I imagine. Is there a 'better' way to solve this issue?

EDIT: The parent component also gets data from another child component so it needs to be the one that does the POST API call.

Comment: What does the `emit()` trigger? An output to parent component? If so what does the parent do to insert into DB?

Comment: @Arcteezy use promise.

Comment: Yea, the emit just triggers an API call to add the new review to the database essentially

Comment: Instead of emitting an event, call the API. Use an observable or promise and wait for it to resolve. Then you can route to required component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the API and return the response as an observable. On successful response from the subscription, you can redirect to the required component.

**data.service.ts** :

> I assume you have a POST API and you're passing the review as payload.

```
addReview(review: string): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(
        // Your POST API,
        review,
        httpOptions
    )
}
```

**app.component.ts** :

```
this.dataService.addReview(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(
    response => {
        console.log("Response :",response)
        // On success, route to reviews
        this.router.navigate(['/reviews']);
    },error => {
        console.log('Error :',error)
    }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the parent component pushes information it receives from the reviews component and other components throughout the stepper process so I can't call the POST API from the reviews component, it must be called from the parent I think

Comment: Then do the same API subscription in parent component and route from there.